# Canvas ignores Css filters

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, filter, html2canvas

A `#h2c` div contains two `img` element  `.i` with filters `sepia(100%)` and `blur(2px)` respectively.
Now when used  `html2canvas` a library to convert div to canvas and onrendered.
  `window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));`
this image lacks the filters applied to the `.i` in div `#h2c`.
Why does this happened and how to fix it?